# Is there a way to switch code indentation from tabs to spaces across the project, and to keep 'hg annotate' functionality?

Tags: python, mercurial, indentation

There's a rather large oldish Python project that historically has the most (95%+) of the code base using tabs for indentation. Mercurial is used as a VCS.

There're several inconveniences in using tabs. It seems that 4 spaces became a prevailing indentation way within Python community, and most of code analysing/formatting software messes up with tabs one way or another. Also, most (pretty much all, actually) of team members that are working on the project are preferring spaces to tabs, thus would like to switch.

So, there's this fear of losing the ability to track who was the latest modifier of a specific line of code... because if all of the lines of code are converted to use spaces-based indentation from using tabs-based one, and then the change gets committed to the mercurial repository, that's exactly what's going to happen. And this feature (hg annotate) is too useful to consider a possibility of sacrificing it.

Is there a way to switch the indentation method across the project without losing the Mercurial hg annotate functionality? If there is, what would be the most painless way?

Answer (score 3):

If you were to do the replacement of each tab with 4 spaces, you could still get a reasonably correct result from `annotate`, just use the switch that ignores changes in whitespace:

```
hg annotate -b text.txt
```

You could also use `-w` to ignore all whitespace in the comparison, but `-b` appeared to the best match: ignoring the case when some whitespace was changed into a different whitespace.

This would, however, ignore *all* lines where only whitespace had been altered, which would ignore changes in indentation and leave them attributed to the previous alteration of the line.

See [hg help annotate](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#annotate) for more.

Comment: I would like to add to the above the suggestion that you do the switch in a single __big__ hit - possibly after telling all the team to take a night/weekend off - there are a number of tools that you could do to make it reasonably painless, then you will have a single "special" commit & push.  This will make life easier as you can tell everybody they need to pull afterwards.  You might also like to consider adding some pre-commit hooks to ensure that all new commits do not use tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new repository and, by using suitable scripts, populate it with each commit of the previous history *BUT* with the files automatically modified from what was actually committed to the same with the tabs replaced.  Basically your script would need to checkout the initial file set and get the commit details replace any tabs in the file set and then commit to the new repository with the original commit details.  It would then move on to the next change set, generate and apply paches, filter for tabs again and commit, etc.  There is a blog [here](http://linux.goeszen.com/mercurial-timestamp-on-commit-how-to-record-datecode-as-commit-date.html) about doing something similar.

You could do this offline and autmatically and on an agreed upon date replace the repositories on your server, (keeping a copy of course), with the modified one - just remember to tell your team that they need to pull before doing any work the next day.

I would strongly recommend implementing pre-commit [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html), so as to ensure that you do not get polluted should anybody try checking in an old format file.  They would probably be worth having in place on the new repository before starting the process.

### UPDATE

Having written the above I finally came up with the correct search terms and found you [hg_clone](https://bitbucket.org/bitsquid/hg_clone/src/2e198887c18c/hg-clone.rb) which should do **exactly what you need**, to quote the opening comments:

```
# Usage: hg-clone.rb SOURCE-DIR DEST-DIR --target TARGET-REVISION --cutoff CUTOFF-REVISION --filter FILTER

#
# This program clones a mercurial repository to a new directory, changeset by changeset
# with the option of running a filter before each commit. The filter can be used for
# example to strip out secret data (such as code for unused platforms) from the code.
#
# --target TARGET-REVISION
#    The revision that the DEST-DIR should be updated to. This revision, and all its parent revisions
#    will be copied over to the dest dir. If no TARGET-REVISION is specified, the latest revision in
#    the repositiory will be used.
#
# --cutoff CUTOFF-REVISION
#    If specified, this should be a short revision number that acts as a cutoff for synching. If you
#    specify 100 for instance, no revisions before 100 will be brought over to DEST-DIR. Revisions
#    that have parents earlier than revision 100 will be reparented to have 100 as their revision.
#
# --filter FILTER
#    Specifies a program that should be run in the DEST-DIR before committing each revision.
```